# Injecting a constructor with an object returned by a method in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

In my spring application-config.xml I have

```
<bean id=“shapeFactory" class="com.shapes.ShapeFactory" />

<bean id=“shapeHelper" class="com.shape.ShapeHelper">
    <constructor-arg value=“#{shapeFactory.createDefaultShape()}” />
</bean>
```

However in my shapeFactory class i also have a method whose signature is something like

```
 public Shape createShape(final Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>>,
                                              final Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>> ,
                                              final double ,
                                              final double ,
                                              final int , final double)
```

How can i instantiate shapeHelper object by calling createShape which takes different parameters as its arguments.

EDIT: To make the example simple, if let say i had

```
 public Shape createShape(final double ,
                          final double ,
                          final int , final double)
```

How could have i called any of the above method and make the return Shape the argument of the constructor of shapeHelper?

Comment: It depend in where you want to pass params? at runtime, or at xml config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to create  bean called shape using factory principal

```
        <bean id="shape " class="..Shape" factory-bean="shapeFactory" factory-method="createDefaultShape">
        <constructor-arg name="argNAme" type="java.lang.Long" value="1">
         <!--all args go here ? THEY WILL passed as  parameters to the method createDefaultShape -->
</constructor-arg>
```

then inside your shapeHelper you can simply reference that bean

```
<bean id=“shapeHelper" class="com.shape.ShapeHelper">
    <constructor-arg ref="shape" />
</bean>
```